# Exposing a webserver with high bandwidth behind a firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, webserver, reverse-proxy, firewall

I have to make several on-prem server installations for a video security system.  The servers need to be exposed to the public internet, but I do not have control of the firewall (ie. port-forwarding on the router is not an option).  Additionally, the bandwidth requirements are quite high 100-200mbps. This is what I came up with, but I am open to suggestions:

I created a linux EC2 instance in AWS which has a public IP and DNS.
I then used ZeroTier to connect the linux instances and all on-prem servers via SD-WAN (VPN would be a similar concept).
I then configured the NAT Prerouting table on the linux instance to pass tcp traffic to the various IPs of the on-prem units

ie. if the DNS of the linux instance was "proxy.com" and local IP of the on-prem machine was 123.456.789.101 then:
http://proxy.com:8000 would pass TCP traffic to 123.456.789.101:333

This worked, and was running for several months, but I restarted my Linux instance and must not have saved my config because everything was wiped, and now I cannot figure out for the life of me how I got this working before!

I entered the following lines:
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 7565 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.241.94.154:7563

where 10.241.94.154 is the local ip of my instance, and 7563 is where I want the traffic to go.

But I cannot seem to get it work as before.

So, two questions.

1. Any ideas on where I went wrong, or what I forgot?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To close the loop on this, I was able to fix the problem by `MASQUERADING` the connections so they appear to be coming from the Linux instance, otherwise, they were probably being blocked by the windows machine's firewall.

The line would be:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Still looking for a more ideal and secure way to handle this process, but this will work for now.